# lightdm using too much of CPU resources

Tags: lightdm, cpu

I am using ubuntu 12.04.
The lightdm is taking too much amount CPU constantly.

I have tried restarting the system many times, but no use.
Please help.

**lightdm version : 1.2.3**

Thanks
Saravanan

Comment: The usage is whole 100% in one core. (I am having core i5 processor - 4CPU threads)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem seems to have solved now.
It seems that I was using the proposed updates version of lightdm(**1.2.3-0ubuntu2.6**) which might have some bug still need to be fixed.
I downgraded the lightdm to version **1.2.3-0ubuntu2.5** precise-updates version.And the problem seems to be solved.

Comment: I don't think he is active anymore.